# Как создать класс, дочерний от android.widget.Button в kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Я новичек в Kotlin. Мне нужно создать класс, дочерний от `Button`, содержащий атрибут с нужным мне значением. Как я могу правильно это реализовать? Пробовал нечто похожее:

```
    open class Button
    class cellButton() : Button()
    {
        var side = 0
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MyButton(context: Context) : AppCompatButton(context) {
    var side = 0
}
```